# paypal error in magneto store paypal gateway has rejected request. security header is not valid (#10002

Tags: magento, paypal

I am facing this problem in my magento store. I set up paypal but its giving #10002 error.

I read this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14177/paypal-express-10002-security-header-is-not-valid-error and tried, to give permission to a third party, but I am not able to add third party user name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Magento, there is usually no need to grant third party permissions. You just paste in your API Signature or Certificate credentials (most use Signature). Security Header not Valid means the credentials are not correct. You want to be sure that you copy and paste the credentials with no extra spaces.

Comment: i did but its giving error when i enter card details. error #10548 .. according to paypal this error comes when : "The merchant account attempting the transaction is not a business account at PayPal. Check your account settings." but my paypal is already a business account,,,,,

Comment: What product did you enable in Magento? That error means you are not enabled for the product. If Pro, you will need to apply for and be approved for Pro. If Express Checkout, make sure your email address is confirmed and your account is verified.